# Linux/*NIX и аргументы программы

Tags: linux, bash, консоль, freebsd

Интересует вопрос, каким образом работают аргументы программы на разных ОС (Debian/Linux, FreeBSD, Solaris, etc).

Для примера, возьмём стандартную программу  **ls**, и запустим её с аргументами -a -l. Получим вывод. Однако, запустив **ls -la**, **ls -al**, **ls -l -a** - мы получим тот же вывод. Хотелось бы узнать - данное поведение как-то контролируется разработчиками? Например, я напишу программу, которая будет работать со следующими аргументами: **-R -t -dT**, как юзер сможет запустить программу, как показано на примере **ls**? Это 'регулируется' автором тулзы?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Это 'регулируется' автором тулзы?

И да и нет. Программист сознательно должен предусмотреть это в своей программе, но для этого есть стандартная библиотечная функция — [`getopt()`](https://www.opennet.ru/man.shtml?topic=getopt&category=3&russian=0) и встроенная команда оболочки [getopts](https://rtfm.co.ua/bash-funkciya-getopts-ispolzuem-opcii-v-skriptax/). Обе они стандартизированы POSIX. Интерфейсы к `getopt` есть практически во всех языках.

> Например, я напишу программу, которая будет работать со следующими аргументами: -R -t -dT,

Подразумевая, что это `-d` и `-T` — это два разных ключа, на Си типовой пример обработки будет выглядеть примерно так:

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include <unistd.h>

void usage(const char* name) {
  printf(stderr, "Usage: %s" -[RtdT] [-f <file>], name);
}

int main (int argc, char **argv){
  bool recursive=0;
  bool show_directory=0
  bool super_time=0;
  char *file;
  int c;

  while ((c = getopt (argc, argv, "RtdTf:")) != -1) {
    switch (c)
      {
      case 'R': recursive    = 1;    break;
      case 't': process_time = 1;    break;
      case 'd': show_directorye = 1; break;
      case 'T': process_time = 0;    break;
      case 'f':
        file = optarg
        break;
      case 'h':
        usage(argv[0]);
        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
      case '?':
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
      default:
        assert(0);
      }
  }

  // do stuff

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

glibc также предоставляет функцию `getopt_long ()`, которая поддерживает парсинг длинных аргументов вида `--some-option` и `--some-option-with-arg=val`, но это только расширение GNU.

> Для примера, возьмём стандартную программу ls, и запустим её с аргументами -a -l. Получим вывод.

Такое поведение большинства утилит, кстати также [стандартизовано](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap12.html) POSIX.

Comment: [getopt()](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getopt.html) и, самое главное, [utility syntax guideline](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap12.html#tag_12_02)

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, да, спасибо, я случайно удалил абзац со ссылкой...